# Can I splice UF-B and NM-B in a junction box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, junction-box

I am trying to determine if it's ok to run UF-B from the meter panel and ***tie in to the NM-B cable underneath the addition and tying them together with wire nuts inside a junction box***. (This is to eliminate the underground NM-B to the service panel which is totally within a wet location).

There are two yellow NM cables (14/2 I believe) which are going from the main panel box outside to the underside of the addition built on to the mobile home. I believe one is for the 4 ceiling fans, and the other is for the main room outlets (6 in total).

Can I run 12/2 UF-B from the main panel breaker to somewhere under the addition and tie the UF and Romex together (with wire nuts) within a junction box? The UF-B will be underground and the Romex will be attached to the floor joists before going in to the junction box.

Thank you

Comment: Yellow is almost aways 12/2 not 14/2. White may be either depending on age.

Comment: When you say running from main panel box are you referring to the service pedestal or the distribution panel that is part of the mobile home?

Comment: @isherwood - The original installers ran regular Romex underground from the addition to the Meter panel outside of the house. I am hoping to run UF-B from the meter panel and tie in to the Romex underneath the addition and tying them together with wire nuts inside a junction box.

Comment: NoSparksPlease - the service panel with the meter attached.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can connect UF-B (wet use) cable and NM-B (dry location) cable in a junction box. There's no rule that says you have to continue with UF all the way to a device. As long as the junction box and the NM are in perpetually dry locations it's all fine.

The inverse is also allowed. You can extend a NM-B circuit with UF to serve a wet location outlet, for example.

In my case, I have UF extending a circuit to power a yard shed, in which NM extends the UF. It's a NM-UF-NM sandwich.